# Deployment to Wildfly with failure message: undefined (CORBA.INTERNAL: minor code: 208)

Tags: java, deployment, wildfly, hostname, corba

In our production environment (which was working fine for years) we started getting a rather confusing message during deployment of a war application.

`WFLYSRV0014: Replacement of deployment "public-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" by deployment "public-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: undefined`

so basically no real message just undefined. In the log files i found another error message

`WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.iiop-openjdk.orb-service: org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 208  completed: No`

I found that this message pops up when there is a problem with resolving the hostname but when i tried to run a simple java program to determine the hostname, there was not any problem. The following line was resolved without any problem

`String hostName = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();`

We tried to set the logger to lower logging level, but we didnt get any new error messages.

The environment is: Wilfly 11.0, Java 1.8.0_171, Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Has the `/etc/hosts` file on the machine been updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the whole jboss.iiop-openjdk package from wildfly because it was not used in our project and that resolved the issue. I still dont know what was the cause but probably it can be resolved also with an upgrade of wildfly